Cable current rating for high frequency applications
I am looking for power cables for high-speed motors, with frequencies up to 700Hz. All the tables that I find online are referred to 50/60Hz applications. I am not able to find derating factors related to skin and proximity effect. Where can I find these information? Is there any standard I can look into? I find it quite challenging to define the ampacity of a high-frequency cable.
The cable manufacturers refuse to give me information on this regard.
EDIT: the cable cross section that I am considering is 95mmSQ. The calculated skin depth is 2.46mm

700 Hz is pretty much the same as 60 Hz for small cables. As long as your cable diameter is < 2 * skin depth, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect to calculate, then you can ignore it.

For a cable 60 Hz ~= 700 Hz. You will be fine.

The cross section of the cable is 95mmSQ. Would this info help?

You can approximate the useful crosssection as a hollow cylinder with wall thickness of a skin depth and outer diameter of your cable. Then calculate this for the two skin depths at rated and actual frequency.

That's what I did so far, but I was wondering if there is a better approach. Also, what about the proximity effect in the case of a multi-core three-phase cable?

They probably do give you this information, but you need to calculate it or estimate it yourself.
Any conductor with a magnetic field will have some kind of inductance associated with it. You can estimate this just with some tools to get a basic idea of the inductance: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/wire-self-inductance-calculator/
If you want to delve further, you'll need to consider how the wire is constructed. IE how many conductors and the cross sectional area of each one. Usually a 2D field solver  would be good, since these are time consuming to learn and run, it would be better to experiment with a section of cable.

Rule of thumb: #0000 wire is close to the skin depth limit at 60Hz.  (Most applications, at currents higher than this [#0000 rating], use multiple cables in parallel, or bus bar -- which is flat to both take advantage of skin effect and the increased power dissipation surface area.)
700Hz is 35/3 times higher frequency, or sqrt(35/3) times shallower skin depth.  This suggests around 7 AWG will be satisfactory.
A proper calculation such as RF Skin Depth Calculator with Formula | Skin Depth Frequency Calculation Tool - Pasternack gives 2.46mm, or about a 5mm cable (4 AWG or so) should be adequate.
If you need higher total ampacity (I guess from your area need, it's around 200A?), you will need to use enough cables of this size in parallel to make the total.  Make twisted pairs or quads of +/-, or triples of phases, and put all of them into the same conduit/shield (pursuant to any code rules dictating conduit/raceway sizing, conductor derating, paralleling, etc. of course).
Note that the skin depth calculation applies only to the infinite half-plane geometry, and is different for cylindrical (wire) geometry; the same scaling rules apply however (i.e. the sqrt() dependence on resistivity and frequency).  It's different further for stranded cable, which does slightly better (can be 5-20% improvement) than solid wire of equal cross-section.
Would also be safe to choose a gauge or two larger than this, which won't increase the cross-sectional area proportionally (because the middle-most strands will be carrying less current) but gives a little more cross-section, and more surface area for heat dissipation.
Mind, this is an engineering solution, not necessarily consistent with any given electrical code in your area or elsewhere.  You will need to consult with a professional to ensure facility wiring is compliant with applicable regulations.
